# Выравнивание текста в кнопке WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-шаблоны

При использовании шаблона текст в кнопке отображается в левом верхнем углу, как это исправить?

Код шаблона:

```
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="Button_Round">
            <Border CornerRadius="20">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStopCollection>
                            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#5a55a5"></GradientStop>
                            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#a27cb9"></GradientStop>
                        </GradientStopCollection>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
                <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True"></ContentPresenter>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Код стиля кнопки

```
       <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="210"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#5a55a5"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
```

Код кнопки в MainWindow.xaml

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource Button_Round}" Content="Давайте начнем" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0, 310, 0, 0" Click="Button_Click">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а вы на каждый элемент будете задавать вопрос по выравниванию, или поймете основной механизм? Вот в предыдущем вопросе вам сказали, установить `VerticalAlignment="Center"`, что мешает сделать тоже самое и здесь? Вот подумайте просто логически, вы переопределили кнопку, сделали ей `Border` с закруглением, внутрь поместили контент, условно у вас получилось `<Border><TextBlock Text = "Давайте начнем"/></Border>` Вот вам надо текст поместить по центру, что будете делать? Наверно установите `TextBlock `-у `VerticalAlignment` и `HorizontalAlignment`, верно? Тогда в чем проблемы?

Comment: `<Border VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">` либо `<ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">`